# Add and remove templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

Lets say I have this 'Model'

```
 var lists = [
  {

    title:          'Default title',
    image:          '/img/default.jpeg',
    section:        [
                      {   name: 'Default Name',
                          description: 'Default Description'
                      }
                    ],
    activity:       ['default']
  }
];
```

Here is the view templates

```
<template name="main_list_view">
   {{#each list.section}}
      {{> section}}
   {{/each}}
   <a id="addSection" href='#'>Add Section</a>
</template>

<template name="section">
   <li>{{section.name}}</li>
   <li>{{section.description}}</li>
   <a class="deleteSection" href='#'>Delete Section</a>
</template>
```

I need help w the logic for add more sections and remove a specific section from the colection.

I have checked mongoDB and looks like I have to use something like addToset and $unset for update the model, but I really only want to remove them from the view, cause I want the default model to remain the same always.

So how I remove and add Templates to the view when the user clicks Addcontent, and remove the specific view when the user clicks remove ? is there a Meteor way to do it ? So a user clicks addContent and a new section template is rendered or removed if clicks remove.

Answer (score 0):

Removing one should be simple enough. First, it might help to add the id of the section in your delete link:

`<a data-id="{{section._id}}" class="deleteSection" href='#'>Delete Section</a>`

```
Template.section.events({
  'click a.deleteSection': function(evt) {
    Sections.remove($(evt.target).data('id'));
  }
});
```

Adding one is a different story, because it depends on exactly what you want to happen when you click the `addSection` link. Does that link render a form that creates a new `Section` on submission? Or does the handler to that link create a `Section` object and fill in the values?

**Edit**

It was pointed out that `Sections` is not a collection. I should've seen that. Making it into a collection would be an obvious way to deal with that. So instead of:

```
   {{#each list.section}}
      {{> section}}
   {{/each}}
```

You'd have:

```
{{#each sections list._id}}
  {{> section}}
{{/each}}
```

And in your js file:

```
Template.main_list_view.helpers({
  sections: function(list_id) {
    return Sections.find({ list_id: list_id });
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could move the "section" template up to the parent and then you could add the list_id as a data attribute on the link::

```
{{#each list.section}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
  <li>{{description}}</li>
  <a data-id="{{list._id}}" data-name="{{name}}" data-description="{{description}}" class="deleteSection" href="#">Delete Section</a>
{{/each}}
```

Then in your js file:

```
Template.section.events({
  'click a.deleteSection': function(evt) {
    var list = Lists.find($(evt.target).data('id'));
    var section = { name: $(evt.target).data('name'), description: $(evt.target).data('description') };
    sections = list.sections;
    sections.splice(sections.indexOf(section), 1);
    Lists.update(list._id, $set: { sections: sections });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, the add will add a new section and fill the values

Comment: Your answer is not working @samo, cause Sections is not a collection and you cant call Sections.remove

Comment: Its like have nested models, no one have a good example of nested models w meteorjs ??

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for the fact that there is no Sections collection. I sure hope you have a Lists collection...